# Cannot find the webelment it is inside a frame and near a web table

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The element is highlighted with `**` near the tag it's inside a frame but Java code is unable to switch the frame below is the source and WebDriver code.

This is the source HTML:

```
<iframe id="Ifrm1510295770939" class="abs0 hw100" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" src="/ecp/UsersGroups/ResourceMailboxes.slab?reqId=1510296120132&showhelp=false" title="resources - Microsoft Exchange" ldhdlr="1" cf="t">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html lang="en-US" dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1">
<body tabindex="-1" umc-topregion="true" onkeydown="if(typeof(HandleShortcutKeys) == 'function') {HandleShortcutKeys(event);}" role="application" scroll="no" aria-busy="false">
<noscript> <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=/ecp/error.aspx?cause=noscripts" /> </noscript>
<form id="aspnetForm" class="hw100" role="form" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" action="./ResourceMailboxes.slab?reqId=1510296120132&showhelp=false" method="post">
```

the element I want to find is highlighted with:

```
  <div class="aspNetHidden">
a class="ToolBarButtonLnk" href="#" role="button" onclick="javascript:return false;" title="Search" aria-label="Search" aria-disabled="false">
  *<img class="ToolBarImage CommandSprite search-default" alt="Search" src="https://r1.res.office365.com/ecp/15.20.197.22/themes/default/clear1x1.gif" title="Search">
  <span class="ToolBarButtonImageAlter">Search</span>
```

[image]

I have used switch the frame but not working. Java code I wrote in Selenium:

```
 public class Verify {

    WebDriver driver;
    Actions ac1;



    public void Login1() throws InterruptedException
    {   


          driver = new FirefoxDriver();
          driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://outlook.office.com/ecp");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='cred_userid_inputtext']")).sendKeys("BSL_Test1@c02.mwslab.net");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='cred_password_inputtext']")).sendKeys("Xoraan*(987");
    //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='cred_sign_in_button']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    ac1 = new Actions(driver);
    ac1.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).perform();
    }

    public void admincentre() throws InterruptedException
    {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='priNavLnk' and @index='1']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Menu_Resources']/a")).click();
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='ResultPanePlaceHolder_ctl00_ctl02_ctl01_ResourceMailboxesListView_contentTable']/tbody/tr[10]/td[1]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000); 
    }

    public void trial()throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    //WebElement fra = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='Ifrm1510207939402' and @title='resources - Microsoft Exchange']"));
    int count =driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).size();
    System.out.println(count);



    driver.switchTo().frame("Ifrm1510207939402");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("img[@class='ToolBarImage CommandSprite search-default']")).click();

    //List<WebElement> numberOfFrames=  driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
    //System.out.println("Total Number of iframes present are : "  +numberOfFrames.size()); 
    }

    @Test(priority=0)
    public void start() throws InterruptedException{
        Login1();
        admincentre();
    }

    @Test(priority=1)
    public void start1() throws InterruptedException{

        trial();
    }



    }
```

Tried with even implicit and explicit wait no working.

Comment: Can you update the Question with the exact error you are seeing with your code and at which line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty much evident from the `HTML` you shared that the `id` attribute of the `<iframe>` tag is dynamic. So we have to switch to the frame properly and click the intended element as follows :

```
WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@id,'Ifrm') and contains(@title,'resources - Microsoft Exchange')]")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@class='ToolBarImage CommandSprite search-default']/span[@class='ToolBarButtonImageAlter']")).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

The id of the iframe change always. Furthermore, the way of you execute the switch:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("Ifrm1510207939402");
```

isn't correct.

Before you have to execute the correct switch:

```
        WebElement iframe= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@title='resources - Microsoft Exchange']"));
        driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
```

and after you can search the interested element.

An advise: don't use the `thread.sleep`. Try always to use the [explicit waits](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp).

The entire code:

```
        driver.get("https://outlook.office.com/ecp");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='cred_userid_inputtext']")).sendKeys("user");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='cred_password_inputtext']")).sendKeys("password");
        WebElement button = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
                .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("cred_sign_in_button")));

        button.click();
        Actions ac1 = new Actions(driver);
        ac1.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).perform();

        WebElement recipients = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
                .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='priNavLnk' and @index='1']")));

        recipients.click();

        WebElement resources = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
                .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("Menu_Resources")));
        resources.click();

        WebElement iframe= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@title='resources - Microsoft Exchange']"));
        driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);

        WebElement tt = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
                .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//form[@id='aspnetForm']/div[@id='wrpdv']/div[@id='ResultPanePlaceHolder_ctl00']/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div[@class='cttPane']/table/tbody/tr/td/div[@id='ResultPanePlaceHolder_ctl00_ctl02_ctl01_ResourceMailboxesListView']/div[@class='ToolBarContainer TopCtrl']/div[@id='ResultPanePlaceHolder_ctl00_ctl02_ctl01_ResourceMailboxesListView_ToolBar']/div[@class='ToolBarItem  ToolBarButton ToolBarButton InlineSearchBarCommand  EnabledToolBarItem']")));


        tt.click();


        /*to return to default content
          driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        */
```

**PS:**

maybe is better if you remove your credentials from your example.

Comment: it worked David .....sure will only use explicit wait here after ..........merci beaucoup

Comment: @Ashok Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

I see another id of the iFrame in the html then in your code. Try to switch with this id:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("Ifrm1510295770939");
```

Comment: yes Koen i used it but still it didn't switch...finally used explicit wait to switch it .............Thank you..........

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Thread.sleep();
```

with long wait time.

Comment: It worked with explicit wait vaibhav..used Thread.sleep() but it didn't work....thank you